# what is the right sequence of these codes?

Tags: java, android-studio

i am making a quiz game and I need to randomize each question. how do I properly code these. pls help. thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Question {

    public String questions;
    public String[] options;
    public String answer;
}

    List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();

    Question question1 = new Question();
    question1.question = "Which part of the plant holds it in the soil?" ;
    question1.options = {"Petals", "Roots", "Stem", "Flower"} ;
    question1.answer =  "Roots" ;


            questionList .add(question1);

            Collections.shuffle(questionList);
```

Comment: you should store questions and their options in a local file. map it and show to the end user.

Answer (score -1):

This

```
Collections.shuffle(questionList);
```

is shuffling only a list of Question objects (and you have only one question...), not the options...

You should use instead either another logic, like generating a random integer between **0** ans **options.length-1** or using a sortable data structure

Comment: can you give me an example :(